# Undefined variable $POST /form-validation/public/user HTTP/1.1 Accept:

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm trying to insert the data in the database. What is the simplest way to insert a data in the database.

### Form

```
<form action="{{ route('user.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
```

### App/Http/Controllers/TutorialController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest as UserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\User;


class TutorialController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function store(UserRequest $request) {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $$request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

        $user->save();

    }
}
```

### routes/web.php

```
Route::get('user', [TutorialController::class, 'index'])->name('user.index');
Route::post('user', [TutorialController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
```

I tried to insert post

```
$user = User::post([
'name' => $$request->name,
'email' => $request->email,
'password' => $request->password,
]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent: inserting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168377/laravel-eloquent-inserting-data)

Comment: It's ``User::create(...)``, not ``User::post(...)``

Comment: yes. i tried to redo in User::create()

Comment: i did add the $post but the error is.. syntax error, unexpected token "=>", expecting "]"
$user = User::create($post[

Comment: why are you adding ``$post``, you don't need. Also,, you have ``$$`` in the line ``'name' => $$request->name,``

Comment: remove the $. it works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest as UserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\User;

class TutorialController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('user.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code. same error.

Comment: remove the $ in 'name' => $$request->name. it works.